# BigQuery TIMESTAMP differences

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Can someone please shed some light on the differences between the following two queries.
Dataset: chicago_taxi_trips

```
"""
               WITH RelevantRides AS
               (
                   SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM trip_start_timestamp) AS hour_of_day, trip_miles, trip_seconds
                   FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
                   WHERE EXTRACT(DATE FROM trip_start_timestamp) > '2016-01-01'
                   AND EXTRACT(DATE FROM trip_start_timestamp) < '2016-04-01' AND trip_seconds > 0 AND trip_miles > 0 
               )
               SELECT hour_of_day, COUNT(1) AS num_trips,
               3600 * SUM(trip_miles) / SUM(trip_seconds) AS avg_mph
               FROM RelevantRides
               GROUP BY hour_of_day
               ORDER BY hour_of_day
               """
```

and

```
"""
               WITH RelevantRides AS
               (
                   SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM trip_start_timestamp) AS hour_of_day, 
                          trip_miles, 
                          trip_seconds
                   FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_taxi_trips.taxi_trips`
                   WHERE trip_start_timestamp > '2016-01-01' AND 
                         trip_start_timestamp < '2016-04-01' AND 
                         trip_seconds > 0 AND 
                         trip_miles > 0
               )
               SELECT hour_of_day, 
                      COUNT(1) AS num_trips, 
                      3600 * SUM(trip_miles) / SUM(trip_seconds) AS avg_mph
               FROM RelevantRides
               GROUP BY hour_of_day
               ORDER BY hour_of_day
               """
```

I am not sure why the WHERE conditions are not equal.

I ran both queries expecting them to return the same results, but they do not.

Comment: How are the results different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following query:

```
with temp as (
    select cast('2015-12-31 23:59:59 UTC' as timestamp) as ts union all
    select cast('2016-01-01 00:00:00' as timestamp) as ts union all
    select cast('2016-01-01 00:00:01' as timestamp) as ts

)
select
    ts,
    ts > '2016-01-01'
from temp
```

In a timestamp-to-date comparison, the date is as of midnight when the date begins.  In your 2nd query, a timestamp that occurs on '2016-01-01' will be greater than '2016-01-01'.